# Why is useState not triggering a re-render on a string

Tags: react-hooks, use-state

i have the following code:

```
const [error, setError] = useState('');

const errorResponse = error => {
  // do something
  console.log(error.message); // Network Error!
  setError(error.message);
}
```

I call the errorResponse method in a `.catch()` block when an axios call fails. However, when the error message gets passed onto the errorResponse, and the `setError()` method subsequently, the re-render did not happen and my error message is not displayed for the user.

Not sure what I am doing wrongly here.

Comment: I've made a simple sandbox for you, if you can edit it to your non working situation, I can help you more !
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shockley-ktwjk?file=/src/App.js:0-825) Let me know!